# Why was this edit (that added a tag) rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

[My edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/263392) on [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/317183/i-want-to-sell-a-couple-if-skins-on-the-steam-market-but-my-phone-authenticator) was rejected 2 times (and 1 time approved) with the following message:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

I'm wondering how that is the case, since adding a *relevant* tag does make a post easier to find.

I think the [steam-mobile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam-mobile) tag is **relevant** here because the question is clearly about the Steam mobile app as it is mentioned:

- In the title
- In the question's body
- And even in the currently only answer to the question, complete with multiple screenshots

The asker reported that he could not see conformation requests **in the app** and the current answer explained how this could be fixed (**in the app**).

So why was this edit removed? Was it an error? Or am I missing something?

Comment: For what it's worth, I would have approved the edit in question if I saw it in the queue, but ultimately it was rejected 2-1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah this edit makes complete sense, so I've mod-approved it. Perhaps the reviewers thought it was the first use of the tag, given your edit description.

Either way, it's approved now.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that the edit description "added (new) tag" could be confusing, however, "added tag" gave the message "Your edit summary must be at least 10 characters." and prevented me from submitting the edit. I think next time I will use a bit more words.

Comment: @Bassie-c try "Added relevant tag"

Comment: Noted. Great idea!

Comment: Or even "added steam-mobile since the question is clearly about the mobile version of steam, as referenced in the title and question". The more information in your edit summary, the better.